# date picker on jsoup

Tags: datepicker, jsoup

I need to post the date for datepicker, but i don't know how to. I just know about post the value of textbox and button using jsoup, but how about datepicker? It doesn't have input name like others. Can you give an example how to post the date from datepicker using jsoup? Many thanks.

This is the code for post the value of textbox and button, but i dont know how to post the value of datepicker.

> Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/somescript").data("text1", "yourText1Value")
>   .data("button1", "Submit")
>   .post();

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker field is just a simple input type="text" like this : `<input id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" type="text">`

so something like this should do:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/somescript").data("datepicker", "08/14/2012") .data("button1", "Submit") .post();
```